# Android SlidingDrawer : How can I slide an activity just using motion event except handle

Tags: android, android-activity, sliding

I'd like to make layout just like *avast! Mobile Security* app's main view.

Is it sliding drawer or just using `overridePendingTransition` animation effect?

I think it is sliding drawer. But there is no handle. This makes me confused.

How can I slide an activity like this app?

check the app [`here`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5hdmFzdC5hbmRyb2lkLm1vYmlsZXNlY3VyaXR5Il0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Navigation Drawer in Android since last google io. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

It's added in recent version of SupportLibrary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want sliding menu you can check this:

[Github slide menu](https://github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu)